# component wrapped in keep-alive but created gets triggered everytime I switch pages

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component wrapped in a keep-alive tag because I dont want the created hook to be called everytime a user revisits this component. My problem is, that the created gets called everytime when I change tabs. Am I misunderstanding the mechanics of keep-alive?

```js
<template>
  <keep-alive>
    <v-card>
     
    </v-card>
  </keep-alive>
</template>
```

Comment: I think you should wrap the `<keep-alive>` around the component in your parent and not in the child component itself.

Comment: I tried that too but did not make any difference when I made the keep alive arround the component inside the view page.